# Get duration of QMediaPlaylist object

Tags: qt, playlist, duration, qmediaplayer

I create a player for audiobooks - when you open a folder with mp3 file, whole list of them is added to playlist and List View. And i have a Label, which suppose to show duration of the whole book. But player->duration returns only a duration of current track, and if i go through the loop and do playlist->next() every step, player->duration returns 0. I know about Phonon and file metadata, but i need to do this without using it.

Comment: Doc says that duration property may not be available when initial playback begins and suggests connecting a slot to the durationChanged(qint64) signal. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#duration-prop

Answer (score 0):

I am attaching a source code of a working project, you can use. When the player changes the file, the duration is changed and printed out. To loop within files, there is a need to wait till the decoder completes reading the media file. See the code below and the comments.

This is mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

bool done =false;


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
    playlist = new QMediaPlaylist(player);
    playlist->setPlaybackMode(QMediaPlaylist::Sequential);
    player->setPlaylist(playlist);

    connect(player, &QMediaPlayer::durationChanged, this, &MainWindow::on_durationchanged);

    //connect(player,&QMediaPlayer::)
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   playlist->addMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("Ar_today.mp3"));
   playlist->addMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("Ar_sunday.mp3"));
   playlist->setCurrentIndex(0); //set the first file
   while (done == false) //wait till the duration is read
   {
       QApplication::processEvents();
   }
   done = false;    playlist->setCurrentIndex(1); //change to the second file
   while (done == false) //wait till the duration is read
   {
       QApplication::processEvents();
   } //this way you can loop through files


   player->setVolume(80);
   player->play();
   qDebug() << player->errorString();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    player->stop();
}

void MainWindow::on_durationchanged(qint64 duration)
{
    done = true;
    qDebug() << "duration = " << player->duration();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QMediaPlaylist>
#include <QDebug>
extern bool done;


namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();


private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

     void on_durationchanged(qint64 duration);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QMediaPlayer* player;
    QMediaPlaylist* playlist;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

## In the form, create 2 buttons, one called pushbutton to play and the other is pushButton_2 to stop